# Parse config file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I would like to get the first pattern in single quote.

```
$ cat test 
if (response == 'good' and name == 'john')
```

With this command, I get the last pattern in single quote :

```
$ sed -nr "s/.*'(.*)'.*/\1/p" test
john
```

I want it to return

> good

Answer (score 1):

the following should do the trick

```
sed -nr "s/[^']*'([^']*)'.*/\1/p" test
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. For instance `awk`:

```
awk -F"'" '{print $2}'
```

or `Perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /'"'"'(.*?)'"'"'/;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this concept

```
sed "s/^[a-z].* ([a-z].*== '\([a-z].*\)' [a-z].*== '\([a-z].*\)')$/\1/" inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you too.
This is a very precise form.